# Is the saving time of record proportional to the number of item lines in NetSuite?

Tags: time-complexity, netsuite, server-side, mergesort, suitescript

I have a SO with 500 item lines.

Once I click the "Save" button, the following code will execute and it may spend about 90 to 120 seconds to finish saving:

```
var so_submit_id = so_record.save({
                    // enableSourcing: true,
                    // ignoreMandatoryFields: false
});
```

I found the more item lines, the longer time the record is saved.
Is the saving time is proportional to the number of item lines? Is there a linear relationship which the time complexity is O(n) between them?

How can we reduce the record saving time? Can we divide the record to update the values and finally merge the child records?

Comment: Can you give a lot more context for this code? What script type is it in? What entry point event is it in? You can probably generally assume the saving time is proportional to the number of line items, but it's likely a higher order than linear. The Sales Order is often the most heavily customized, which means there will be more than just your script running on SO save. Any of those other scripts that iterate over the lines and do something would increase the time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Customisation>Scripting>Scripted Records, how many scripts are running for your record type?

Based on that, you can get results for your "Performance Details" by double clicking on the Oracle | NetSuite logo on the top left of the UI. This will prompt a dialogue box depicting what, and how long things took. A few tests on the number of lines and you can plot a curve for your system.

Hope this added value for the testing!